# Form still redirect to PHP with preventDefault

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

EDIT:

This was related to a typo elsewhere in my Javascript. I had forgotten to check the Javascript console. Thank you for your comments.

This is my first post on this site. I have been reading it for a long while though.

I am working on a login form utilizing jQuery, AJAX, and PHP. Several times now I have run into the problem where I am redirected to the PHP page where I see the echoed data I wanted returned. I have tried to figure this out but I am stuck.

EDIT:

I did include jQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

HTML:

```
<form name="login" id="loginForm" action="login.php" method="post">
    <label for="usernameInput">Username: </label>
    <input type="text" name="usernameInput" id="usernameInput" placeholder="Username" autofocus required>
    <label for="passwordInput">Password: </label>
    <input type="password" name="passwordInput" placeholder="Password" required>
    <input type="submit" name="loginSubmit" value="Log In">
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
function login () {
    $('#loginForm').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var formObject = $(this);
        var formURL = formObject.attr("action");

        $.ajax({
            url: formURL,
            type: "POST",
            data: formObject.serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data)
            {
                $("#loginDiv").remove();
                if(data.new) {
                    $("#setupDiv").show();
                } else {
                    statusUpdate();
                                   /* EDIT: Changed from dummy text 'continue()' */
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                $("#loginDiv").append(textStatus);
            }
        });

    });

}
```

Call:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        login();
    });
```

PHP:

```
// Main
if (isset($_POST['usernameInput'], $_POST['passwordInput']))
{

  require "hero.php";

  // Starts SQL connection
  $sql = getConnected();
  $userArray = validateUser($sql);

  if ( $userArray['id'] > 0 ) {

    sessionSet($userArray);

    $userArray['user'] = (array) unserialize($userArray['user']);
    $userArray = json_encode($userArray);
    echo $userArray;

    exit();
  }
  else
  {
    echo 'Username does not exist';
  }
}
else 
{
  echo "Please enter a username and password.";
}
```

I know I have not included everything, but here's the output:

{"id":"11","name":"st5ph5n","new":true,"user":[false]}

So everything up to $userArray is working as expected. Why is this not staying on index.html and instead redirecting to login.php?

Thank you for any responses.

Comment: did you include jquery on your page? Are you getting any errors in your console before submitting the form? If both of those are ***no*** then your code should be working.

Comment: `continue` is a reserved key word, don't use it as function name

Comment: try e.stopPropagation(); however if you use this method please be aware that this will prevent the event bubbling up the event chain